# What's the right way to mix and use boric acid spray for fleas?

Tags: pest-control, chemicals

My fleas were begging for it, so I let them have it.. sort of

After an hour of trying to figure out why my sprayer won't spray properly I have realized boric acid is not soluble in water. Or is it ?

As i have read over the interwebs, boric acid = borax + salt in a 5:4 mix ratio. There were crystals in the water + boric acid mix (about 200g per 4L) which would clog my sprayers. Would I be guessing correctly those insoluble crystals were the salt ?

I took out the crystals, put the solution in my sprayer and sprayed all over the place. Upon drying a noticeable film of something got laid out where I have done the spraying. Is that the borax ?

And for future referents, should we buy just borax instead of boric acid if we wanted to dissolve  it in water ? What ratio borax : water if so ?

Comment: Boric acid plus salt will not eradicate an established flea infestation. You need permethrin or some other serious insecticide.

Comment: Your "reading of the interwebs" does not do your chemistry teacher proud. A compound is not a mixture and your ratios appear dubious even then. Regardless, I would strongly suggest an insect growth regulator (IGR)  or a product combining an "adulticide" to kill the fleas and an IGR to prevent the many thousands of eggs from growing into new fleas.

Comment: alcohol might be a better solvent, if you can find any right now...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer: heating the water helped a lot. I have boiled 1.5L, mixed with 0.5L tap water (summer time) and dissolved 100g boric acid in it completely.

Comment: No Kidding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid

Comment: But the problem is, when the water cools back down, its capacity to hold solution will be reduced, and if that means it’s over-saturated, the stuff will recrystallize *wherever it wants to*.